# Comparing a user input string to one that is stored in a pointer. C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Im trying to get a programme im writing to compare what a user inputs to a word stored in a pointer. The code is below

```
int c_s(char*, char*);

int main()
{
printf("Hate crime reporting system\n\n\n");

printf("If the crime you are reporting is an emergency,\nplease call 999, do 
not proceed any further with this form\n\n\n\nPlease press enter to confirm 
you have read the above and continue\n");
char enter = 0;
while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') { enter = getchar(); }


int a;
long long int g;
char *b, *e;
char *c = "witness";
char *d = "yes";
*c = (long long int) &g;


 printf("Are you a victim or witness of the crime?\nPlease answer 
 victim/witness\n");}
 scanf("%s", b);  
    int r = strcmp (b, c);
    if(r == 0){    
    printf("Do you know who the witness is? Please answer yes/no\n");}
    scanf("%s", d);
       int f = strcmp(e, d);
       if (d = "no") goto NEXT;
       if(e == 0){
         printf("Please enter their details including phone number and 
address");}

NEXT:
```

When a user answers "witness" to the question "are you a victim or witness", i want the code to continue and ask the next question, and then the same again if they answer "yes or "no" to the question "do you know who the witness is?". When i run this code i get an overflow error. Im new to coding so if anyone could provide sample code on how to make this work i would greatly appreciate it. Im not sure whether im using the pointer wrong or whether i should be using an array?

Can someone also please explain how i would make this an if statement, meaning if the user types in "victim" as the answer to the above question, the programme continues to "NEXT:"

Comment: There is no memory associated with pointer `b`.  You cannot put data into that pointer until there is memory for it.

Comment: `*c = (long long int) &g;` - yikes

Answer (score 1):

Before we even get to your string problems, look at this line:

```
printf("Are you a victim or witness of the crime?\nPlease answer victim/witness\n");}
```

It ends with a `}`, which seems to match the start of `main`.
At this point, you've ended the main function, and the rest of your code is not even part of a function.  This likely won't even compile.

---

To get string input, you must make sure there is memory available for the string:

```
char *b;     // WRONG: Uninitialized pointer.
char b[500]; // CORRECT: b can hold up to 499 bytes (+ one \0 at the end)
scanf("%s", b); // Get input into the memory you declared.
```

---

Also, you must make sure the memory is writable:
*this problem is more subtle, and many C programmers have a hard time with this*

```
char *d = "yes";     // WRONG: "yes" is a constant string in your program, it cannot be changed.
char d[200] = "yes"; // CORRECT: d is 200 bytes, and is initially set to "yes".  It can be changed later.
```

---

Even after using `strcmp` correctly in parts of your program, you still tried to do:

```
if (d = "no") goto NEXT;
```

- You cannot do string comparisons this way in C.
- Even if you could, it would use a `==` not a single `=`
- Never use `goto` *(unless you wish to be attacked by a [velociraptor](http://%20https://xkcd.com/292/))*.

---

On this line, you reference variable `e`, but you never set it to a value.

```
int f = strcmp(e, d);
```

On this line, you treat `e` like it is an integer, but it was declared `char*`
*(and it still does not have a valid value)*

```
if(e == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

A string can never be "stored in a pointer", and that's exactly your problem. You just feed `scanf()` your uninitialized pointer `b`. This has a random value and doesn't point to any usable memory, so when `scanf()` tries to write there, your program crashes.

Solution: provide memory to write to for `scanf()`. Either declare `b` as an array (e.g. `char b[256];`) or use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate memory. Then make sure you don't write more bytes than you reserved. `scanf("%s", ...)` will always overflow any buffer if the input is larger, so use a field width with `scanf()` -- see the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Better yet, don't use `scanf()`. You might want to read my [beginners' guide away from scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is an uninitialised pointer. The effect of your `scanf` is therefore undefined behaviour. Something like

```
char b[100];
```

Will allocate 100 bytes of space on the stack to `b`. You will then need to take steps to make sure that no more than 99 bytes are read from stdin by the `scanf`.

`c` is first initialised to point to the string `"witness"` which is good, but this line:

```
*c = (long long int) &g;
```

Sets the first byte to the lowest byte of the address of `g`. It's completely unnecessary, get rid of it.

The next `scanf` scansd into `d` which is set to a literal string`"yes"` I think this is undefined behaviour too, but it's wrong, in any case. You should be allocating some space to `e` (as per `b`) and scanning into that.

Your comparison after the `strcmp` should use `f` not `e` and the `printf` should really have a `\n` on it.

By the way, this example shows the value of using descriptive variable names. In two places, you have used the wrong variable but if you had named them descriptively e.g. `f` => `comparisonResult` you might have avoided confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes to keep you going:
1. When declraing a string, you must specify it's size. A string is a an array of chars, and an declaration of an array in c should be given with a size (with at least the number of chars+1), as so:

```
char c[10] = "witness";
```

2. [strcmp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) returns 0 if strings match.

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong as string cannot be stored in the pointer

```
char *c = "witness";
char *d = "yes";
```

to do so you need to first assign the memory for that pointer

```
char *c=(char*)malloc(strlen("witness")*sizeof(char));
char *d=(char*)malloc(strlen("yes")*sizeof(char));
strcpy(c,"witness");
strcpy(c,"yes");
```